# Nextjs 13.4 how to pass server env variable to a client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

this is my client component, I made it client and not server because of useState needed by the HCaptcha component which needs to set the token in a state.

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import axios from 'axios'
import HCaptcha from '@hcaptcha/react-hcaptcha'

export default function Contact(){
    const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
    const [msgSent, setMsgSent] = useState(null)

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();

    const onSubmit = async (values, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (!token) {
            return alert('Captcha token required')
        }

        try {
            axios.post('/api/email/send', {
                name: values.name,
                email: values.email,
                message: values.message
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status <= 250) {
                    setMsgSent(true)
                    e.target.reset()
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                //console.log(error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
    
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {msgSent &&
                            <span>sent</span>
                        }
                        {!msgSent &&
                            <span>not sent yet</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div>some fields</div>
                    <div>
                        <HCaptcha
                            sitekey={ process.env.HCAPTCHA_SITEKEY }
                            onVerify={ setToken }
                            onError={ () => setToken(null) }
                            onExpire={ () => setToken(null) }
                        />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

the problem with this is that the `process.env.HCAPTCHA_SITEKEY` is not being read, since it's server only, I can prefix it with NEXT_PUBLIC_ but that'd expose it publicly, I tried to wrap the HCaptcha in a server component and send the state upward via props but later found out we can't use server components inside a client component

Comment: And why don't you wrap `HCAPTCHA_SITEKEY` with a server component that has access to this key? Finally, I don't think that there is a safe way to have a client in the client without exposing it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Site key !== secret key. Since it needs to be rendered in the browser, prefixing it with NEXT_PUBLIC_ is the right approach.

Comment: makes sense, HCaptcha is a component for the frontend at the end of the day, they also let you bind the key to certain domains so I guess I'm good. still curious to better understand the whole 'use client' 'use server' nesting madness tho